# C++: sorting an array, last number duplicated twice

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm a C++ newbie coming from basic and I'm having trouble with sorting an arrays. The intention is to generate 10 random numbers and then have them sorted, but the last number seems to be duplicated twice. I've tried all different sorts of loops but I can't seem to figure out why this occurs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int c,x;
    x = 1;
    int swap1, swap2;
    int list [9];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++){
          list [c] = rand() % 100 + 1;
         std::cout << list[c] << std::endl;

    }

    while(x <= 9){

        for(int c = 0; c <=9;++c){

            if(list[c] > list[x]){
            swap1 = list[c];
            swap2 = list[x];
            list[x] = swap1;
            list[c] = swap2;

        }

    }
    x = x + 1;
    }

    std::cout << "//////////////////////////////////////////////////" << std::endl;

      for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++){

         std::cout << list[c] << std::endl;

    }


}
```

Here's the output. To the left of the /////// is the random numbers generated, to the right of the line is the array after the sorting. The issue is the last number is duplicated twice, and a number is missing.

71
72
99
93
21
83
8
78
44
31
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
8
21
44
71
72
78
83
93
99
99

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: your array has 9 elements but you are accessing 10. Change `for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++)` to `for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)`

Comment: Well the question says he wants 10 random numbers so the loop is correct and `int list [9];` is not big enough.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: change your array declaration to `int list [10];` : it will hold 10 integers and the last index will be 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare an array of size 9, but you want 10 elements. To fix, change the declaration of the array to `int list[10];`

A few things to note on the side.

- You have a variable `int c` in the beginning, but you create a new variable inside each for loop called `c` as well. (Get rid of the first variable declaration)
- Loop conditions are generally of the form `< size`, not `<= last_index`.
- You mix pre and post increment in your loops. Pick one (hopefully pre increment)
- Do not call your variable `list`, (A very common name for a *class*).

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) by reading out of bounds in your `for` and `while` statements:

```
for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++) {
    list[c] = rand() % 100 + 1; // UB!
```

also in

```
while (x <= 9) {
    for (int c = 0; c <= 9; ++c) {
        if (list[c] > list[x]) { // UB!
```

But at this point it doesn't really matter as UB has already been invoked earlier. Arrays in C++ are zero indexed so when `c` becomes `9` the program invokes UB. Change your array declaration to:

```
int list[10];
```

Or change your upper boundary to be less than `9`, not less or equal than `9`.

Answer (score 2):

Arnav Borborah's answer shows how to fix the code into a C program that uses std::cout. I upvoted his answer, because it shows where the error is. Here is the C++ way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const size_t size = 10;
    int list[size];
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));

    for (auto &v: list) {
        v = rand() % 100 + 1;
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::sort(std::begin(list), std::end(list));

    for (auto v : list) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "//////////////////////////////////////////////////" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Interesting someone down voted this.  Doesn't this approach solve all the problems mentioned and is simpler?

Comment: The C++ way wouldn't use a C Style Array, it would either use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). (Not the downvoter)

Comment: Somebody down-voted after I accidentally hit "save" before I edited it.

Comment: as Aarnavs answer merely suggests fixes to OPs code, but does not encourage writing "C with cout" I would suggest you to remove that first sentence. Not my downvote, btw, but I was considering it for just that reason

Comment: I did not intend to suggest that Arnav was promoting bad practice. I upvoted his answer.  BTW, I see nothing wrong with using a static array in the example.

Comment: @JiveDadson I don't either, but since we were all talking about the C++ way, we  might as well go all the way with it.